# An improvement of USAMO 2001

Tags: inequality

> Let $x,y,z \geqslant 0$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$, prove that
>   $$\tag{1} xy+yz+zx +\frac{(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2}{8} \leqslant 2 + \frac{x+y+z-1}{2}xyz $$

**Here is a brief history about this inequality**

The USAMO 2001 stated that

> For all $x,y,z \geqslant 0$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$ then
>   $$\tag{2}xy+yz+zx-xyz \leqslant 2$$

There are several solutions for this inequality. The natural approach is to use the trig substitution $x=2cos (A), y= 2cos(B),z=2cos(C)$  and utilized the identity
$$\tag{3} cos^2(A)+cos^2(B)+cos^2(C)+2cos(A)cos(B)cos(C)=1$$

About three years ago, an improve version of USAMO 2001 was proposed, due to the guy a.k.a Mudok in [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h502934). With the same condition, his problem stated that

$$\tag{4} xy+yz+zx-\frac{x+y+z-1}{2}xyz \leqslant 2$$

Based on the trig sub in $(3)$, one can see that his inequality is indeed stronger than the original.

I think the version I posted is the strongest one. I could not solve it after several attempts.

Comment: See here a beautiful luofangxiang's solution: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h581974